# pythonライブラリhmmlearnのAttributeError

Tags: python, macos, 機械学習, jupyter-notebook, scikit-learn

**実行したコード**

```py
from hmmlearn import hmm
model = hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=5, n_iter=100)
model.covars_
```

**吐き出されたエラー文**

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-8ccf3a3ae39c> in <module>
----> 1 model.covars_

/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hmmlearn/hmm.py in covars_(self)
    161     def covars_(self):
    162         """Return covars as a full matrix."""
--> 163         return fill_covars(self._covars_, self.covariance_type,
    164                            self.n_components, self.n_features)
    165 

AttributeError: 'GaussianHMM' object has no attribute '_covars_'
```

**試したこと**
・model.covars_に適切なサイズの行列の代入

他の変数model.startprob_,model.transmat_,model.means_も同様のエラーが起きていたがこちらはこの方法で解決できた。

・公式ドキュメントを読む
・githubの開発コードを読む

自分の今の能力では解決に至るまでの理解は敵いませんでした...。

**詳細**
本来であれば上記の実行によりmodel.covars_が生成されるのですが、いつの間にか当該のエラーが起きるようになってしまいました。
他にもhmm.GaussianHMMの引数であるinit_paramsでcovarsやmeansなどの
ハイパーパラメータが初期化されるようになるはずなのですが、そちらの方も機能していないことが分かりました。
今までは本ライブラリは通常通り使えていたのですが今日突然動かなくなってしまい、エラー文もヒントが乏しく自力での解決で行き詰まってしまったためこちらに質問させて頂きました。

どなたかご教授いただけると幸いです。
以下が自分が参考にした公式のドキュメント達になります。
https://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html
https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn

**エラーその2**

```py
/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hmmlearn/hmm.py in covars_(self)
    162         """Return covars as a full matrix."""
    163         return fill_covars(self._covars_, self.covariance_type,
--> 164                            self.n_components, self.n_features)
    165 
    166     @covars_.setter

AttributeError: 'GaussianHMM' object has no attribute 'n_features'
```

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/231761

Comment: [ここ](https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn/blob/master/lib/hmmlearn/hmm.py#L210) で初期化していますので、例えば `X = numpy.random.normal(size=(1000, 5))` として、`model._init(X)` を実行する必要があります。そうすれば `model.covars_` が設定されます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
修正を反映させて頂いたのですが、次のエラーが出てしまいました。
恐らくこちらの方が根本的な問題である気がするのですがこちらの方もみていただけないでしょうか...

Comment: [ここ](https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn/blob/master/lib/hmmlearn/hmm.py#L211)と[_check_and_set_gaussian_n_features()](https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn/blob/master/lib/hmmlearn/hmm.py#L33)で n_features をセットしています。先の例で言いますと、`model._init(X)` を実行すると model.n_features には `5` がセットされます(`X.shape[1]`)

Comment: なるほど、l.225の_init()の時点でn_featuresは定義されているのですね。
指摘してくださった箇所を参照しながら変数を追うことで、自分のエラーに気付き無事に解決することができました。
ありがとうございました。